# How do I show the same content on both screens?

Tags: 12.04, screen, monitor

I use 12.04 LTS on a HP 6530b (laptop) and an external Samsung SyncMaster T220HD.
It works, however - the laptop and the external monitor shoes as dual monitors and I should like to have only one monitor (same screens on both monitors).
How do I change this behavior?

Comment: In other words, I want to prevent dual screens.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system

```
screens
```

and there find option

```
monitors
```

there You can find a checkbox saying:

show the same display on both screens

The situation can be different when using prop drivers. If so tell us what VGA card do You have and what drivers are You using.

Regards

Comment: I am missing out completely - I cant find system, properties, monitors. I only find the system properties dialog where I can select monitors, but no option for "same display on both screens". I use the standard Ubuntu screen driver.

Comment: how about when You click the system actions button (right upper corner by default), there should show up a menu with optios like system properties and below should be screens. Can you find this?

Comment: OK,thanks - speaking about the same thing. I have an option to mirror(translated from my language) the screens - that is probably the same as "same display on both screens". When I select this option I get same content, but horrible screen resolutions.

Comment: So You don't have this menu at all?

Answer (score 0):

In 12.04 press the Dash button (The purple and white button at the top left), type Displays, and click on the Displays icon. The Displays control panel will take a couple of seconds to come up.

After it comes up you can select the `Mirror displays` checkbox and then press the Apply button. If it is working you can accept the change. If you don't it will go back to what you now have in 30 seconds.